# Select hebrew from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

honestly I am coming here after trying everything I could find online in order to fix that problem but nothing worked..

I have a phpmyadmin database table that encoded to `utf_general_ci`, when I insert data in Hebrew into it it works fine and I can see the Hebrew in the table on PhpMyAdmin, but when I need to retrieve the Hebrew data from the table that's when the problem starts...

right now I am using a simple sql query to select data from the table and I tried every code that should fix it I could find online but nothing seems to work.

my current code is:

```
<?php

    $db = "android";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";


$sql = "select * from sample;";


$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array($row[0],$row[1]));
}
$str = json_encode(array($response));
echo $str;
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

and the output of the Hebrew word is `\u05d4\u05d9\u05d9` what seems like a different encoding, my php file is encoded to UTF-8 and I am using npp to write it.
please try helping me out on this one cause I couldn't find an answer

Comment: this looks like url encoded output or something else. Try to do all charsets and collations to utf8_general_ci

Comment: @KostasDrak what do you mean? in the PhpMyAdmin my collations is already utf8_general_ci

Comment: Seems like you might need to add proper headers, set the charset to utf8 in your PHP and HTML headers. And what does the raw output from your query look like? If you do `var_dump($row);` inside your loop?

Comment: @Qirel Hey , thanks for your answer, I wrote the var_dupmp in my loop and it is actually giving me the Hebrew words but with incorrect length like this:C:\wamp64\www\getdata.php:23:string 'היי' (length=6)                                                                                                    I don't really know what it means or what to do with it.. also I tried putting a header on the php page (I don't have an html page) and it didn't changed anything

Comment: That's because special characters (like Hebrew, Greek, etc) are multi-byte characters, so don't worry about the length. You'll need to pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as a second parameter to your `json_encode()`, making it `json_encode(array($response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: It's good practice to render the entire pipeline with the same charset, so I recommend you set the file-encoding, PHP header `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and HTML head (inside `<head>` tags) `<meta charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: @Qirel Thank you so much!! it worked

Comment: @Qirel my bad, didn't see you already answer with the good flag `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

Answer (score 1):

This is a `json_encode()` behaviour, by default Unicode char are escaped as `\u...`

Try with [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) :

```
<?php
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```